# Access: Dropdown list of CheckBoxes

Tags: forms, ms-access, checkbox, drop-down-menu, combobox

I'm trying to figure out how to replicate something I did in VB.Net. I'm trying to create a dropdown box of checkboxes so that users can pick multiple options. I've been able to create the dropdown box, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to add checkboxes, and how to make it so long sentences aren't cut off (see highlighted).[image]

I'm trying to stay away from using any type of VBA code, but if that's the only way to do it I guess I'll have to bite the bullet.

Comment: Don't waste your time. The controls are essentially static (not customizable beyond built-in behavior) in Access and their properties do not often provide the detail configuration that you request.  Access is not VB.Net and certainly does not have the proper framework to create custom controls like this, even with VBA.  Even if you hack something together using multi-valued fields as in the posted answer, you'll never get it to treat your long strings as you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the only way to display checkboxes allowing multiple selection from a combobox is to use a multi-valued field, e.g.:

[image]

However, I would personally suggest avoiding this approach, as multi-valued fields can be a pain to work with and go against database normalisation rules.

Instead, you might want to look at using a list box permitting multiple selection, either via Simple multiple selection (where each click selects another item), or Extended multiple selection (where the user holds <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select multiple items).

---

Another alternative might be to use a continuous subform, with each record displayed alongside a checkbox, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: I think to start off with i'll go with the simple multivalued combobox approach, I'm really just at the beginning of understanding access functions for now and that seems the easiest. I'm wondering how you do it though? I'm guessing it's a simple "Yes/No" somewhere but I can't find it

Comment: Although the answer contains a suggestion to avoid this approach, it does not fully explain that by making a ComboBox support multi-value fields, it actually changes the hidden table schema of the bound column.  It creates an automatic, hidden many-to-many bridge table which then places special requirements and restrictions on queries, etc.  I have personally used them before to a certain advantage, but DO NOT use them just to get the checkbox control behavior.  Only do this if the multi-value field provides a necessary data-driven purpose.

Comment: It is essential for the user to be able to scroll through a list, and pick multiple options. I can't think of another way to do this without making it very ugly as there are around 50 options for the user to choose from. At the end of the day, I just need the options chosen to be put in one string that I can put in one other table. I'm not doing much manipulating or anything of the finished string

Comment: I suggest two lists with --> and <-- buttons (and implement double clicking) to select items betweens lists.  This is a reasonable, usable alternative within Access.  Really this style is used in other contexts, and for very long lists can be better anyway, so that the user can see a concise list of selected items rather than scrolling through to see what is selected.  Despite my strong comments before, I total understand your need.  It's just the I and others have already explored this option and there are no robust checkbox-list solutions that I'm aware for Access.

Comment: @CPerkins I have updated my answer to offer another alternative option.