# Multi-select combo box returning odd character rather than the value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a working multi-select Combo Box on my main form.  I need to fill a table with the selected items for other drop down lists in subsequent forms in my database application.
This is the code that is not working for me:

```
Private Sub CollTypes_AfterUpdate()
Dim db as Database
Dim cct as Recordset
Dim i as Variant

Set db = CurrentDB()
Set cct = db.OpenRecordset("dbo_tbl_DefaultVehicleList", dbOpenDynaset)

For i = 0 To Me.CollTypes.ListCount - 1
   If Me.CollTypes.Selected(i) then
      cct.AddNew
      cct!CollectionMethodLU = Me.CollTypes.ItemData(i)
      cct!CruiseID = Me!CruiseID
      cct.Update
   End if
Next i

End Sub
```

The ItemData(i) is returning a strange character that looks like a ÿ instead of the expected value. The CollTypes RowSource is a SQL select of four fields from a lookup table and is bound to the first column, which is an AutoNumber. Could the fact that it is an AutoNumber be causing this? Here is a screen shot of the form and the Properties box.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIak0.png)

And here is what the drop down looks like:
[image: Form in Use with Drop Down]

Incidentally, the "combo box" is set up to have four columns but the Column Widths are set to 0";0";0";2" so that only the last column is shown.

OK, so I got it working.

```
Private Sub CollTypes_AfterUpdate()
Dim db As Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim cct As Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim varItems As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set cct = db.OpenRecordset("dbo_tbl_DefaultVehicalList", dbOpenDynaset)

currcruise = Me!CruiseID
varItems = Me!CollTypes.Value

strSQL = "DELETE * FROM dbo_tbl_DefaultVehicalList WHERE CruiseID = '" & currcruise & "'"
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

For i = LBound(varItems) To UBound(varItems)
    cct.AddNew
    cct!CruiseID = currcruise
    cct!CollectionMethodLU = varItems(i)
    cct.Update
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Combo boxes in Access cannot be multiselect. Do you mean a list box?

Comment: It is a Combo Box.  And it is working well.  When you drop down there are check boxes next to each thing in the list and an OK and Cancel button at the bottom.  The result returns a comma delimited list of the selected items.  In my research, I did see others saying that combo boxes can't be multiselect, but apparently, Microsoft added that feature in later versions.

Comment: Your comment sounds like a multi-valued field selection dropdown box (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55287538/3820271)), which is *not* a regular combo box with its regular properties. Your edited question doesn't though.. can you add a screenshot of design view with the properties window?

Comment: Interesting. This sure looks like a "real" combo box. :) Is there a specific property that enables the checkboxes per item?

Comment: Side note: *The result returns a comma delimited list of the selected items.* - You could simply read the selected items from this string, using the Split() function.

Comment: As @Andre said, multi-select combobox is only possible with a multi-value field and does not work same as a regular combobox. It looks like a normal combobox in design view but it works differently. The result is NOT a comma delimited list (not a CSV string), it is a set of pointers to records in a hidden table. Cannot attach files to comment, edit question to provide more information.

Comment: Interesting, the person that developed the application but does not know vba sent me something to try that actually worked: INSERT INTO dbo_tbl_DefaultVehicalList ( CollectionMethodLU, CruiseID )
SELECT dbo_tlu_Collection_Method.CollMethID, dbo_tbl_CruiseInformation.CruiseID
FROM dbo_tbl_CruiseInformation INNER JOIN dbo_tlu_Collection_Method ON dbo_tbl_CruiseInformation.CollTypes.Value = dbo_tlu_Collection_Method.CollMethID;

Comment: `ON dbo_tbl_CruiseInformation.CollTypes.Value =` ok, so it *is* a multi-valued field. Mystery solved. I have never used them, I thought it would look differently in design view. The `dbo_` naming is a bit confusing too, since that is normally for SQL Server linked tables (which cannot have multi-valued fields).

Comment: Yes, @SusanGottfried, that SQL is expanding multi-value field so each element is retrieved as a record (pulling from hidden table). That's what referencing Value property of multi-value field accomplishes. Seems to me you are essentially duplicating the multi-value field data into a normal table. Alternative would be UNBOUND multi-select listbox and that would require VBA to save selected items as records. Expect that multi-value field to eventually give you more grief in other SQL actions.

Comment: if the combo is a multi-select mulit-value result? Then it will automatic update the table behind, and you should not need any code at all. In fact, you can NOT even stop Access from updating the hidden table that drives this multi-value combo. In other words, when you leave that record and return, the boxes checked will remain as such, and thus no real "after" processing should be required. What you can do to get that list is query against that one table and that column. Try using the query builder, you see a ".value" option - and using that will "expand/explode" the row data into rows.

Comment: An update for everyone.  I got it working.  I needed to take the items selected in the multi-valued list and add them to another table for default values so that in subsequent forms, I used only those values in drop downs. I put the new code in the original post.

Comment: Big thanks to everyone for your help.  This is a valuable site and I appreciate you all.